# Exception: No provider for Array! When initializing variable through the constructor shorthand

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular-promise

I'm currently learning about Angular2 through the [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) website. Following the implementation of dashboard.component.ts (View below).

(A1: My implementation)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero }     from './hero'
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html'
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{ 

    constructor(private heroes: Hero[], private heroService: HeroService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroList => this.heroes = heroList.slice(1,5))
    }

    goToDetail(hero: Hero):void{

    }

}
```

I get the following error.

(A2: Stacktrace)

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/dashboard.component.js class DashboardComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for Array!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/dashboard.component.js class DashboardComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for Array!
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:429:31)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:406:13
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:203:28)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6242:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:202:34)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:96:43)
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:462:57
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:37)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6233:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:235:42)
Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/dashboard.component.js class DashboardComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for Array! ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/dashboard.component.js class DashboardComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for Array! {...} Error: No provider for Array!
    at NoProviderError.Error (native)
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1255:38)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1739:20)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1770:20)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3366:23)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3394:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3357:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3166:25)
    at NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7222:56)
    at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9303:52)
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/dashboard.component.js class DashboardComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for Array! {...}
```

However, when I write it the same way found on the webpage (view extract below), I no longer receive the error (A2). Why is this happening?

(A3: Implementation provided by the tutorial)

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero[] = [];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
  }

  gotoDetail(hero: Hero): void { /* not implemented yet */}
}
```

From the tutorial, defining a constructor the way I implemented (A1) should have the same result as the code provided by the tutorial (A3) in terms of creating an initializing the heroes list. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you missed the fact that doing it the first way, your constructor has an additional parameter of type `Hero[]`, and that Angular needs to call that constructor and thus provide the required arguments and thus find a provider that provides an instance of `Hero[]` to pass to your constructor.

You should just not have the heroes as part of the constructor, since Angular must not pass heroes when constructing the component. The component fetches heroes by itself using the service.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I still have troubles understanding your answer though, mainly because I'm still new to the angular concept. 
Could you redirect me to a source that talks further about this case? Or simply elaborate your point further :)


**Update** I have reread the part about "providers" in the angular.io dependency injection tutorial. They didn't mention thoroughly how this works. But for the moment I am assuming that by declaring the component as @Injectable(), this will cause angular to attempt to find a provider for each parameter in the constructor, is this correct?

Comment: A component is always injectable. And all the constructor arguments are thus services that are injected by Angular. Your array of heroes  is not a service that can be injected, and it shouldn't be an argument anyway, since the constructor doesn't even use this argument value.